# Strange behavior trying to connect SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite

Well i have some time trying to connect to DB like this:

```
public static Connection connect(String url) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url); // (1)
        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:settings.db"); // (2)
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

then i call it from main...

```
connect("jbdc:sqlite:settings.db");
```

that only works when i put the url in literal (2), but doesnt when i put as variable (1)

Other info:

- JDK (lastest)
- Netbeans 8
- GNU/Linux - Arch64
- Encoding UTF-8 in editor
- JDBC driver - https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Any thoughts? im stuck, thanks.

EDIT:

The stacktrace

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jbdc:sqlite:settings.db
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:74)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at lyoneel.Sandbox.connect(Sandbox.java:59)
    at lyoneel.Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:23)
```

Comment: can you please add the errors you get when you run it as a variable (and verify that when you `System.out.println` that variable, it in fact contains what you thought yo uhad put in?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans done, stacktrace added, there is nothing more than i put there, and yes i put System.out.pring before posting here, all as spected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
connect("jbdc:sqlite:settings.db");
         ^^^^ - should be j d b c not j b d c
```